# Styling <form> tag

Tags: html, css, forms

I am familiar with HTML/CSS but am not advanced by any means.

I am having difficulty styling my form element. 
[image]

I want to add padding around my form however whenever I do this is only pads the top and the left

[image]

The other issue is that when I re-size the window really small the form tag seems to protrude out of the

[image]

I would like to know what the proper way to do this is.

Also, if you could look over my simple code and let me know if there is a better/more standard way to do what I am trying to do here.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  padding: 5%;
}
section {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
div {} .left-section {
  width: 25%;
}
.right-section {
  width: 75%;
}
.body-left {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 93%;
}
.body-right {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  height: 86%;
}
.header {
  background-color: #808080;
  height: 7%;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #808080;
  height: 7%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
}
form {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
input {
  background-color: #808080;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: small;
  border-color: #555555;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 0;
  height: 80%;
  width: 90%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
button {
  background-color: #808080;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: small;
  border-color: #555555;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 80%;
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  color: #555555;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>whisper</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <section id="left" class="left-section">
    <div id="header_left" class="header">
    </div>

    <div id="body_left" class="body-left">
      <ol id="users"></ol>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="right" class="right-section">
    <div id="header_right" class="header">
    </div>

    <div id="body_right" class="body-right">
      <ol id="messages"></ol>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" class="footer">
      <form id="form_id" action="#">
        <input id="user_input" />
        <button id="btn_id">send</button>
      </form>
    </div>

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

P.S. I have checkout this page but I couldn't find a sufficient answer.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614732/css-styling-of-form-tags

Comment: And this also: http://webdesign.about.com/cs/forms/a/aaprettyforms.htm

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this helps but I switched the padding of 5 pixels from the footer class to the form styling.

```
.footer {
  background-color: #808080;
  height: 7%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
form {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```